# How to make expiration date required?

Tags: date

I need to set expiration date as required for entries on a channel.
So is there any way to set expiration date as required for an entry?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found this add-on by typing "expressionengine, expiration date required" into Google: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/required-expiry-date

Comment: Best answer ever

Answer (score 1):

i cant add comments yet, so i add an answer.

maybe [cp-css-js](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) from pixel and tonic, can help you out.
by adding some javascript validation on the expiration date field

example:

```
$("#expiration_date").prop("required","required");
```

Comment: On EE 2.8.1, they've removed the ID attribute, but yes - in this way, we can handle it out